# .text() returning "<Button />" instead of the button's text

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

Basically what's in the title. I have the following code in a component I am writing a test for:

`<Button>Edit</Button> // <- Material UI Button component`

And this line in my test is failing:

`expect(wrapper.find(Button).text()).to.equal("Edit");`

with this error:

```
assert.strictEqual(received, expected)

Expected value to strictly be equal to:
  "Edit"
Received:
  "<Button />"

Message:
  expected '<Button />' to equal 'Edit'
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Instead of `.text()` try using `.value()`

Comment: @NirjalPaudel I get `TypeError: wrapper.find(...).value is not a function`

Comment: I think you should update a question to have more information. Try `console.log( wrapper.find(Button) )` and see all its properties and methods. I think you will find your answer there

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
import { render, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import {Button} from '../components'

it('renders a button with "Edit" label', () => {
  const { container } = render(<Button />);
  const { getByText } = within(container);
  expect(getByText('Edit')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```